# Can I fork and sell a modified Apache 2.0 licensed project?

Tags: derivative-works, apache-2.0

There is a nice **Apache 2.0-licensed** project that already implements the foundation of a way more elaborate product that I intend to sell as proprietary.

Something like the **70%** of the code will be modified or rewritten, so it's not really like I'm including it as a module or library.

Unfortunately I **cannot release the sources** of the final product as OSS, but it is possible to add credits and acknowledgements.

Would this be legal?

Comment: found this, relates enough: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-use-a-apache-v2-licensed-driver-for-a-commercial-project-without-revealing

TL;DR Yes, but I need to give my customers a copy of the license.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a caveat. If this is critical, you should consult a lawyer and explain exactly what you're doing - this answer isn't legal advice.

What you're describing is allowed under the Apache license. You will still need to comply with the conditions such as providing attribution and including a copy of the license. The best source of information is the license itself; however, the Apache Foundation does provide a nice summary in its FAQs here: https://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN