# Obfuscation and Apache 2.0 license

Tags: apache-2.0

Consider a scenario , I received a software that uses some Apache 2.0 licensed libraries. Software copy I received contains obfuscated codes. Also library part of code is obfuscated.

Since library is coded in java, compiled files will not contain prominent notices of changes made to source. May I ask the author of software where and what changes they made in library? Or May I ask the author to provide a software with atleast not obfuscated library part of code?

Comment: Is the fact that files were modified stated somewhere else in the package? The Apache  license does not specify *how* this notification is made. They could have mentioned it in a README file, for example. Also, remember that the Apache license does not require that source code be supplied, so the fact that files are "obfuscated" is not really a license issue here.

Comment: See also [Can I use a Apache v2 licensed driver for a commercial project without revealing sources of the project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-use-a-apache-v2-licensed-driver-for-a-commercial-project-without-revealing). I.e. it is not required to distribute (unobfuscated) source code to all files.

Comment: So, that implies that I can not ask them for source codes. Right?

Comment: @LaraFlow you are always allowed to ask. But if it it not a copyleft licence then they don't have to respond how you wish.